# salesforce getUpdated method result

Tags: salesforce

i am using salesforce soap api and user `getUpdated()` method for retrieving updated data but it gives data which is not in timestamp which i gives in method.

```
$startDate = "2013-09-04 20:51:36"; and
$endDate = "2013-09-05 20:51:36";
```

Result is

```
$result = getUpdated("contact", strtotime($startDate), strtotime($endDate)));
```

but $result also contain data which is having `lastModifiedDate="2013-08-19 02:50:00";`

what is the reason for this?

there is any mistake in startdate and enddate?

or there is some another way to do this?

Comment: By the way you can ask your question about salesforce directly at salesforce.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

The start & end dates are rounded off to minutes (IIRC, down for start & up for end), so the actual date range is slightly larger than the one you specified in this case.

Presumably there's also some TZ offseting going on, which can also account for some of the difference your're seeing (the date/times in the SOAP message typically have the TZ offset in them, so seeing the actual raw dates going back and forth would also help you).